# JavaFX dropshadow to only a side

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to add a dropshadow effect to only the top of a node.

If I use:

```
-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0.0 , 0 );
```

It add the shadow effect to all borders.

There is another way to create a shadow effect to only one border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. Choose which border you want:

```
node.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, purple, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, -5.0);"); //north
node.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, purple, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0,  5.0);"); //south
node.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, purple, 0.0, 25.0, 5.0,  0.0);"); //east
node.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, purple, 0.0, 25.0, -5.0, 0.0);"); //west
```